# How to avoid that my login cookies are erased by iOS safari?

Tags: ios, http, cookies, https, safari

I wrote a simple web application that uses a login cookie to authenticate users. The login cookie is configured with max time to remain valid 15 days. Unfortunately, safari on iOS keeps erasing the login cookie after a day which requires that the user logs in again. This yields a bad user experience.

Here is an example of cookie header value sent by my web app server. The value, which is not relevant for this question, is secured with encryption and hash value.

```
Set-Cookie: login=AaC64ZMlykIEakiuXBlszJWhPdeFaMAex1DvzU7hD8Ho24TUQNUJBXG1M_m96DKJ-b4YSPCO; Path=/; Domain=www.example.com; Max-Age=1296000; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict
```

No CORS header value is set.

I choose to use a login cookie because it is safer than storing some information in the local storage which can be accessed by any JavaScript code. It is safer when using the HttpOnly and Secure options with https of course.

What can I do to get a persistent login with a web app on safari iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried that saving cookies in the local storage is not safe, just use `NSKeychain` -- a system level local storage on iOS platform.

Comment: Is NSKexChain accessible from Javascript ? I can't find any documentation on it with google. It seam it is for applications written in swift.